# How to change bell icon in local notification using Intel xdk?

Tags: javascript, cordova, intel-xdk

This doesn't work! It only shows a bell icon. Please help me.

I see many questions like this but anyone show how to do in Intel xdk, when I use the plugin local notification:

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        id: 1,
        title: "Test",
        message: "Message test",
        icon: "file://assets/icon_96x96.png"
    });
```

Comment: You say you've seen "many questions like this", but what is your question?  What you want your code to do, and what it does instead?